# I want to make the arrow slider moving the slider image

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a site template. There is a slider have no arrows to moving its images and its moving auto and make arrows for it, but I need help with JavaScript code to make it move the slider. The template is PHP.

```
<div class="row">
<div id="client-logo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
      <div class="owl-wrapper-outer"><div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 4500px; left: 0px; display: block; transition: all 800ms ease 0s; transform: translate3d(-250px, 0px, 0px);">
```

> 

```
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 250px;"><div class="client-logo item"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="login/pic/65874300338.jpg" alt=""> </a> </div></div></div></div>
  </div>
    <div class="nextCircle">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right next" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="prevCircle">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left previous" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
</div>
.nextCircle {
position:relative;
top:-65px;
transform:translateY(-50%);
left:98%;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border-radius: 50%;
opacity:0.5;
background-color:blue;
z-index:19;
}

 .next {
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
color:white;
z-index:20;

}

 .nextCircle:hover{
opacity:0.7;
cursor: pointer;
}

 .fa.fa-arrow-right, .fa.fa-arrow-left {
font-size:30px;
 }

 .prevCircle {
position:relative;
top:-115px;
transform:translateY(-50%);
right:2%;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border-radius: 50%;
opacity:0.5;
background-color:blue;
z-index:19;
 }

  .previous {
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
color:white;
z-index:20;

}

  .prevCircle:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

The arrows at end of the code and I made the CSS code. I need  a Javascript code to make the arrows moves the this slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize Solution 1:

```js
$(function(){
 var i= 0;
 //when the next button is clicked on
 $('.next').on("click", function(){
  //increase the display picture index by 1
  i = i + 1;
  //if we are at the end of the image queue, set the index back to 0
  if (i == $('img').length) {
   i=0;
  }
  //set current image and previous image
  var currentImg = $('img').eq(i);
  var prevImg = $('img').eq(i-1);
  //call function to animate the rotation of the images to the right
  animateImage(prevImg, currentImg); 
 });
 //when the previous button is clicked on
 $('.previous').on("click", function(){
  //if we are at the beginning of the image queue, set the previous image to the first image and the current image to the last image of the queue
  if (i==0) { 
   prevImg = $('img').eq(0);
   i=$('img').length-1;
   currentImg = $('img').eq(i);
  }
  //decrease the display picture index by 1
  else {
   i=i-1;
   //set current and previous images
   currentImg = $('img').eq(i);
   prevImg = $('img').eq(i+1);
  }
  //call function to animate the rotation of the images to the left
  animateImageLeft(prevImg, currentImg); 
 });
 //function to animate the rotation of the images to the left
 function animateImageLeft(prevImg, currentImg) {
  //move the image to be displayed off the visible container to the right
  currentImg.css({"left":"100%"});
  //slide the image to be displayed from off the container onto the visible container to make it slide from the right to left
  currentImg.animate({"left":"0%"}, 1000);
  //slide the previous image off the container from right to left
  prevImg.animate({"left":"-100%"}, 1000);
 }
 //function to animate the rotation of the images to the right
 function animateImage(prevImg, currentImg) {
  //move the image to be displayed off the container to the left
  currentImg.css({"left":"-100%"});
  //slide the image to be displayed from off the container onto the container to make it slide from left to right
  currentImg.animate({"left":"0%"}, 1000);
  //slide the image from on the container to off the container to make it slide from left to right
  prevImg.animate({"left":"100%"}, 1000); 
 }
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
 position:relative;
 width:80%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.owl-carousel img:first-child {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 left:0%;
 top:0;
}

img {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 left:-100%;
 top:0;
}

.nextCircle {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
 left:85%;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 opacity:0.5;
 background-color:black;
 z-index:19; 
}

.next {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 color:white;
 z-index:20;

}

.nextCircle:hover{
 opacity:0.7;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.fa.fa-arrow-right, .fa.fa-arrow-left {
 font-size:30px;
}

.prevCircle {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
 right:85%;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 opacity:0.5;
 background-color:black;
 z-index:19; 
}

.previous {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 color:white;
 z-index:20;
 
}

.prevCircle:hover {
 opacity: 0.7;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="row">
   <div id="client-logo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
      <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510797215324-95aa89f43c33?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=80&w=1200" alt="">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513836279014-a89f7a76ae86?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=80&w=120" alt="">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509149037-37dc57ccbd13?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=80&w=1200" alt="">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470071459604-3b5ec3a7fe05?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=80&w=1200g" alt="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="nextCircle">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-right next" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="prevCircle">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left previous" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

Using the owlCarousel in built Method:

You can add arrows to  owlCarousel using the following param **navigation** and **navText** to show buttons

```
navText: [
            '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
            '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
        ],
```

```js
$('.main-content .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 50,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: true,
    navigation: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: [
        '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
        '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
    ],
    navContainer: '.main-content .custom-nav',
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items: 1
        },
        600:{
            items: 3
        },
        1000:{
            items: 5
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.main-content {
  position: relative;
}
 .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
 .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev, .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  color: inherit;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 100;
}
 .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev i, .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next i {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #cecece;
}
 .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev {
  left: 0;
}
 .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-content">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510797215324-95aa89f43c33?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=80&w=1200" alt="Picture 1">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513836279014-a89f7a76ae86?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=80&w=1200" alt="Picture 2">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509149037-37dc57ccbd13?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=80&w=1200" alt="Picture 3">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470071459604-3b5ec3a7fe05?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=80&w=1200" alt="Picture 4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-theme">
        <div class="owl-controls">
            <div class="custom-nav owl-nav"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first at all thanks to you ... but i didn't understand where i will put this code into my code

Comment: search for owlCarousel init place in your code base

Comment: thank you but it didnt work ... i made an editing in my post by adding the css code for the arrows ... i just need to make this arrows move the slider by java script code.

Comment: Only CSS won't work will add another solution for this

Comment: Hi @mohamedabdallah i have added another customize solution for your situation add this code to your project

Comment: thanks @Rishab ... its work with me now. i just make some modification. thanks again